# navbar breaking on right side on pressing button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On pressing the "schedule a call" button the navbar is breaking on some windows PC while using chrome browser.

http://pracly.com/experts/profile/1

The code for the navbar is as follows:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://pracly.com/">Home</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

The code for schedule a call buttonis as follows :

```
<div class="external-links">
    <a href="http://pracly.com/experts/profile/1#scheduleCall" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Schedule a Call</a>                       
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/faheemahmed" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">LinkedIn</a></div>
```

The image for this phenomenon can be seen from this link : http://imgur.com/SBpGOpF

Comment: Imgur link is broken?

Answer (score 0):

your nav bar may be using a pixeled width(1280px) try using a percentage width.

---

code that works

html:-

```
<html>
<div class="nav"></div>
</html>
```

css:-

```
.nav{
     width:100%;
     height:64px;
     position:fixed;

 /*make sure that te div touches the top */
     top:-22px;
     margin-top:22px;

/*make sure that the div touches the left*/
     left:-22px;
     margin-left:22px;

     background-color:black;
     }
```